# Rendering variable from ngAfterViewInit() is working improperly

Tags: angular, angular-material

Any variable changes in ngAfterViewInit() working lately.

Here the stackblitz app https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vvgbrs

**Component File**

```js
import {ChangeDetectionStrategy,ViewChild,AfterViewInit,Component,ChangeDetectorRef} from '@angular/core';
import {CdkVirtualScrollViewport} from '@angular/cdk/scrolling';

@Component({
  selector: 'cdk-virtual-scroll-overview-example',
  styleUrls: ['cdk-virtual-scroll-overview-example.css'],
  templateUrl: 'cdk-virtual-scroll-overview-example.html',
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
})
export class CdkVirtualScrollOverviewExample implements AfterViewInit {
  index: number = 1;
  @ViewChild(CdkVirtualScrollViewport) viewPort: CdkVirtualScrollViewport;
  items = Array.from({length: 100000}).map((_, i) => `Item #${i}`);

  constructor(private cdRef:ChangeDetectorRef){}

  ngAfterViewInit():void {
    this.viewPort.scrolledIndexChange.subscribe(index => {
      console.log(index);
      this.index = index;
    });
    this.cdRef.detectChanges();
  }
}
```

**HTML File**

```html
<cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport itemSize="50" class="example-viewport">
  <div *cdkVirtualFor="let item of items" class="example-item">{{item}}</div>
</cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport>
{{index}}
```

While scrolling the virtual tab, the index value is changing and it's not a problem.
but when comparing to the console.log() to the index value in the browser, it seems values updating lately, not at the time. What am I missed?

**Differences**

[image]

My goal is the variable must be synchronized. if console output is 1, then the rendered HTML index value should be 1. Kindly help me with what I have missed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to run the change detection inside the subscribe block, so that it runs as soon as you change the scroll.

```
  ngAfterViewInit():void {
    this.viewPort.scrolledIndexChange.subscribe(index => {
      console.log(index);
      this.index = index;
      this.cdRef.detectChanges();
    });
  }
```

Please use this stackblitz instance - https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vvgbrs-pjg28g